# how to run program in exact 10s period (include running time of that program) with java

Tags: java

I've tried using timer.scheduledAtfixedRate(myTimerTask,delay,period), it seems that it will run myTimerTask at first and then wait 10s. So it will at last be total >10s.

```
class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask{
    private static long lastTime;
    public void run(){
        try{
            long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
            callMethod();
            long after = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("callMethod time:"+(after-before)+"ms");
            System.out.println("total used time:"+(after-lastTime)+"ms");
            lastTime = before;
        }  
    }
}
```

callMethod time:

> 102ms

total used time:

> 10102ms

**How can I make it use exactly 10s?**

Comment: What is the real time operating system you use?

Comment: For this you need a real time OS or some sort of real time framework. Possibly can't be achieved by simple Java sleep(). Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system

Comment: You're measuring the wrong thing. `before - lastTime` is what you're interested in when your task is scheduled every 10 seconds. The difference between the `before` times is constant. If you add the time it takes for the task to complete into the calculation you'll get something else.

Comment: Well, isn't that exactly 10s? `after` is the time after executing your method. `lastTime` is the time before executing your previous task. So the time between starting the previous task and the current task is 10102 - 102 which is exactly 10000.

Comment: @zapl,@RealSkeptic, you are right, it's simply my mistake. thanks for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is correct: you are simply not looking at the right number.

Imagine the scenario:

```
lastTime = 0
// first execution
before = 0
after = 102
after - lastTime = 102
lastTime = before = 0
// second execution
before = 10 000
after = 10 000 + 102 (same execution time)
after - lastTime = (10 000 + 102) - 0 // because lastTime was set to before == 0
```

What you are interested in is to see if your `before`s are 10s apart, **independently from the call time**:

```
long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("elapsed time since last execution:"+(before-lastTime)+"ms");
```

Comment: you are right! my mistake, it means the running time of my callMethod() has already been included in the 10s period

Answer (score 1):

This looks like your callMethod takes 102ms.The code execution, JIT etc may take a bit longer in the first runs. It has nothing to do woth when your task starts, relatively it takes 10s. If you expect scheduler to predict execution time then no- that's impossible.

Comment: The `10102` is not the `callMethod` time. It's the time calculated from `after-lastTime`, that is, the total time of the wait + `callMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your `TimerTask`, but not directly start the program (or call your function) but start a new Thread that does the job. Then the `TimerTask` will finish his job of starting the new Thread (almost) immediately and will schedule a new run after 10 seconds (caution: even if your last run has not been finished yet!).

Still, the comments on your question apply - as you're probably not running on a real time operating system, those 10 seconds are not guaranteed. You can just try to get closer.